# LINQ to Entities Query for selecting a content from co table and joining this table with cotypes whereco. cotype ='somevalue' and c.someId is Max?

Tags: linq-to-entities

What will be the LINQ to Entities query for the following SQL Query ?

```
select Verbiage.verbiage 
from Verbiage
join Verbiage_Types on Verbiage.verbiage_type_id=Verbiage_Types.verbiage_type_id
where Verbiage_Types.verbiage_type='ENROLLMENT'
group by Verbiage.verbiage,Verbiage.sequence
having Verbiage.sequence=(
     select MAX(Verbiage.sequence) 
     from Verbiage 
     join Verbiage_Types on Verbiage.verbiage_type_id=Verbiage_Types.verbiage_type_id 
     where Verbiage_Types.verbiage_type='ENROLLMENT')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually the answer is

```
from verbiage in db.Verbiage
join verbiage_types in db.Verbiage_Types on verbiage.verbiage_type_id equals verbiage_types.verbiage_type_id where verbiage_types.verbiage_type == "ENROLLMENT" group verbiage by new { verbiage.verbiage1, verbiage.sequence } into g where   g.Key.sequence == 
(from verbiage0 in db.Verbiage
join verbiage_types1 in db.Verbiage_Types on verbiage0.verbiage_type_id equals verbiage_types1.verbiage_type_id
where
  verbiage_types1.verbiage_type == "ENROLLMENT" select new {
  verbiage0.sequence
}).Max(p => p.sequence) select new { g.Key.verbiage1}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain, but if this doesn't do it, it's pretty close?

```
    Using db As TestContext = New TestContext("connectionString")
        Dim result = (From v In db.Verbiages Join vt In db.Verbiage_Types
                      On v.Verbiage_Type_Id Equals vt.Verbiage_Type_Id
                      Where vt.Verbiage_Type = "ENROLLMENT"
                      Group v.Verbiage, v.Sequence By v.Verbiage, v.Sequence Into Group
                      Where Sequence = Group.Max(Function(n) n.Sequence)
                      Select Verbiage)
    End Using
```